# Barchart is empty when there is no value

Tags: html, jasper-reports, bar-chart

I am using html5 stacked bar charts in JasperSoft Studio.
When there is no value to be displayed, the chart is totally empty and the 0 (zero) line in the y axis goes to the upper. It doesnt really stay at the level of origin.

How can I get the bars of the chart even if there is no corresponding data to be displayed. like a thin line on the level of zero?

And how can I take the 0 line back on the x axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setting `max`to a value is a solution but it has a side-effect for me. It fixes the scale of the axis so if the max value is very big compared to the current data we have, the resulting graph doesnt look nice.

I set `minRange` to 0.1 and it solved my problem. I didnt need to set `max` after that.

Answer (score 0):

You can set "Range Axis Min Value Expression" to 0 in the stacked bar-chart properties section.
To add open property panel click on the chart and select Windows --> Properties then add

```
              Range Axis Min Value Expression   = 0
```

Comment: I couldnt find that property. Can you specify in more detail please? As I said I am using html5 chart

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem where the bar was not showing up correctly. So what I did was I set the max and the min value in the customizer class

In my case the range of the bar was from 0 to 1.

```
NumberAxis rangeAxis = (NumberAxis) plot.getRangeAxis();
rangeAxis.setLowerMargin(0.0);
rangeAxis.setUpperMargin(1.0);
rangeAxis.setRange(0, 1.0);
```